# TYPO3: How to create a complex custom content element from scratch

Tags: php, typo3, element, typo3-8.x, typo3-9.x

Creating a custom content elements is nowdays a very important thing and a lot of developers do not want to dependent on other extensions such as MASK or DCE. Dont't get me wrong these two extensions are remarkable, but it would be great if we all knew how to create our own content element.

TYPO3 does give you the ability to create you own content elements so the question is how do i do it? From start to the end. What do i have to do to create a complex content element?

What complex content element means? That means, storing the information in different tables and be able to get all the content in FrontEnd via relations.

Additionally, how to customize this content element in BackEnd. How to style it. Everything!

**System**: TYPO3 v8, v9, v10 
**Mode**: Composer Mode, Non-composer mode
**Target**: Custom Content element

Comment: This sounds like a huge broad area whereas SO is meant to focus on a particular programming issue with an answer which resolves a particular issue.  This could be more seen as a plug for your own tutorial page.

Comment: If you have ever been occupied with TYPO3 then you should know that all these things I am trying to explain, are important, not only for the specific subject but generally they can be used on a multiple instances inside TYPO3

Comment: I'm not saying there is anything wrong or easy about what you are explaining.  Just not sure it fits into the SO web site though (for reasons in first comment).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried make it as detailed as possible by breaking down every step, explaining almost every line of code and keeping a structure. Since this tutorial is huge, i have uploaded to my own website.

The website is still under Development so if you find something wrong feel free to report it.

What this tutorial contains:

- The concept
- Step 1: Add the content element on the list
- Step 2: Add the content on the dropdown list
- Step 3: Create the tables
- Step 4: Create the TCAs // tt_content relation
- Step 5: Register the icon
- Step 6: Allow external tables
- Step 7: Displaying the content in FrondEnd
- Step 8: BackEnd view
- Step 9: The extras
- Conclusion

If you find something that it could be better formed, do not hesitate to contact me and suggest the changes.

The article: [How to create custom content elements on TYPO3](https://learn-typo3.com/blog/news-detail/how-to-create-custom-content-elements-on-typo3)

Best regards